# why val keyword not working in F#

Tags: f#

Why is the val keyword in the following code snippet causing a compiler error? I need to get the return value and display it.

```
open System

let CylinderVolume radius length =
    let pi = 3.14159
    length * pi * radius * radius


System.Console.WriteLine(CylinderVolume 5.0 10.0)

val cylinderVolume : int -> int -> int
```

Comment: This question is not particularly clear, although I have tried to answer it.  In particular, I assume the line starting with `val` is the output from fsi.exe.  However, this does not match with the definition of `CylinderVolume` given which uses `float` rather than `int`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you have shown as output is not what I get:

```
open System
- 
- let CylinderVolume radius length =
-     let pi = 3.14159
-     length * pi * radius * radius
- 
- 
- System.Console.WriteLine(CylinderVolume 5.0 10.0);;
785.3975

val CylinderVolume : float -> float -> float
```

The `val CylinderVolume` bit is just reporting the type of the `CylinderVolume` object you have defined and the result is printed above it.

Comment: how to get the return result and assign it to a variable

Comment: @user1717327 - `let vol = CulinderVolume 5.0 10.0`.  It is really not clear what you are trying to do though.

Comment: this is my question define a function to calculate volume based on height width and length. invoke the function and assign the returned resut to a value. im in a trouble to assign the return result

Comment: the `let vol = ...` should do that.

Comment: et volume h w l = h*w*l
let answer = volume 10 20 30

Console.WriteLine(answer)

Comment: @user1717327 - that should be fine

Comment: answer variable is taking the return result?? Am i Correct?